# How to read a .json file from a remote server SSH with a shell script

Tags: json, bash, file, jq

I have a json file on a distant server and i want to read data from it using a shell script , i've tried the code below but it did not work ;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/sh

echo "hey"


ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i 
/home/.ssh/cloud_private_key user@adresse << EOF

script
cd /data/Doc1/
databasename=`jq '.ref_Version' re.json`
echo "hello $databasename"
EOF
```

The json file contains

```
 {
 "fileMetadata" : {
 "ref_Version" : "125",}
 }
```

I get :

```
hey
[user@adresse ~]$ [user@adresse data]$ [user@adresse Doc1]$ 
 hello 
[user@adresse ~]$ [user@adresse data]$ [user@adresse Doc1]$ hey22
```

Comment: The newlines here surely aren't correct -- the filename needs to be **immediately** after the `-i`. Is it really that way in your script, or did it get munged on entry to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `JSON` is not valid, you have an extra comma `,` at the end, change it to be:

```
{
    "fileMetadata": {
        "ref_Version": "125"
    }
}
```

With your `jq` command you never specify the sub-key to return the value, it should be:

```
jq '.fileMetadata.ref_Version' re.json
```

**Output:**

```
"125"
```

Comment: This is true so far as it goes, but it doesn't address the full set of issues. Inside the heredoc, the backtick-enclosed string will be run locally, f/e, and the extracted value won't be set on the local machine after SSH exits.

Comment: Similarly, the `echo "Hello $databasename"` will be using the local value of `databasename`, rather than one established after SSH starts. Of course, both these issues could be fixed by changing `<< EOF` to `<<\EOF` or `<<'EOF'`, but that raises the point that this answer to a question about reading input over SSH didn't actually talk about SSH invocation or use at all).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , adding this "<<\EOF " had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running `jq` *locally*, instead of on the other side of SSH:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o pipefail  # consider it a failure if any part of a pipeline fails.

getJson() {
  local address filename_q
  address=$1
  printf -v filename_q '%q' "$2"
  ssh \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -i /home/.ssh/cloud_private_key \
    "$address" "cat $filename_q"
}

if databaseName=$(getJson user@address /data/Doc1/re.json \
                  | jq -r '.fileMetadata.ref_Version'); then
  echo "Hello $databaseName"
else
  echo "Unable to retrieve or parse JSON" >&2
fi
```

Similarly, [as noted by l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343072/14122), your JSON needs some fixes to be well-formed. `{ "fileMetadata": { "ref_Version": "125" } }` is a valid reformulation.